# xCode label isn't updating

Tags: xcode4.5

I've checked all the articles I could on this, and I can't figure out how to fix this.

I'm writing an app that will take the information from a picker (which has two columns) and populate that into a label after a button is pressed. There are no crashes or anything. The only thing in the log is a line that says:
Unknown class ***PickerView in Interface Builder file.
I've attempted clearing the build and 4 other suggestions I found searching around, and I can't get rid of that. PickerView is in the compile sources.

Here is the code for the label updating (just ignore what I commented out, the spacing on iPhone vs the xib were different):

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    NSInteger jobRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kJobsList];
    NSInteger hourRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kHoursList];

    NSString *job = [jobTypes objectAtIndex:jobRow];
    NSString *hour = [hoursTypes objectAtIndex:hourRow];

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@     %@", job, hour];
    int /*one=0, two=0,*/ three=0, four=0, five=0, six=0;
    bool done = YES;
    while(!done)
    {
        /*if(one == 0)
        {
            label1.text = message;
            one = 1;
            done = NO;
            break;
        }
        if(two == 0)
        {
            label2.text = message;
            two = 1;
            done = NO;
            break;
        }*/
        if(three == 0)
        {
            self.label3.text = message;
            [label3 setNeedsDisplay]; // This is a line of something I found online to try
            three = 1;
            done = NO;
            break;
        }
        if(four == 0)
        {
            self.label4.text = message;
            four = 1;
            done = NO;
            break;
        }
        if(five == 0)
        {
            self.label5.text = message;
            five = 1;
            done = NO;
            break;
        }
        if(six == 0)
        {
            self.label6.text = message;
            six = 1;
            done = NO;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out - my bool done was set wrong! it needed to be initialized to NO, and set as YES inside the while.